# How to use conditional to test if a block is passed?

Tags: ruby

For example, if I want to implement a function that does some work A if a block is passed, or work B if there's no block, how do I write the conditional?

```
obj.func {#some code} #func does work A
obj.func              #func does work B
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`block_given?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F) function, if I understood your question correctly.